# Does Windows7 include MSXML 4.0?

Tags: windows-7, msxml

We have a component using MSXML4.0. It failed on a test environment with Windows Server 2003. But works on test environment with Windows 7.

I suspect the first environment doesn't have MSXML4.0. Is that possible? And why later version of Windows have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSXML6 is shipped with Windows 7, MSXML 4 was shipped as an independent downloadable resource. [See Information Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSXML#Versions)